# breaking the for loop repeats the characters

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have this code that works as expected. But for some reason, it is removing the english letters.

```
mydict = {
    b"090": b"0A8",
    b"091": b"0A9",
    b"092": b"0AA",
    b"093": b"0AB",
    b"094": b"0AC",
    b"095": b"0AD",
    b"096": b"0AE",
    b"097": b"0AF",
}

y = "उताऱ्यावर/a"
newlist = list()
for i in y:
    x = i.encode("raw_unicode_escape")
    for k, v in mydict.items():
        if k in x:
            z = x.replace(k, v)
            newlist.append(z)

print(b"".join(newlist).decode("utf-8").encode("ascii").decode("unicode-escape"))
```

returns:

```
ઉતા઱્યાવર
```

The expected output is:

```
ઉતા઱્યાવર/a
```

English letters need no replacement and should be printed "as is".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your logic here:

```
    if k in x:
        z = x.replace(k, v)
        newlist.append(z)
```

If x does not have a match your dictionary then it doesn't get appended to the `newlist`. You will need to account for this case.

```
mydict = {
    b"090": b"0A8",
    b"091": b"0A9",
    b"092": b"0AA",
    b"093": b"0AB",
    b"094": b"0AC",
    b"095": b"0AD",
    b"096": b"0AE",
    b"097": b"0AF",
}

y = "उताऱ्यावर/a"
newlist = list()
for i in y:
    x_replaced = False
    x = i.encode("raw_unicode_escape")
    for k, v in mydict.items():
        if k in x:
            z = x.replace(k, v)
            newlist.append(z)
            x_replaced = True
    if not x_replaced:
        newlist.append(x)

print(b"".join(newlist).decode("utf-8").encode("ascii").decode("unicode-escape"))
```